# how can I limit dot only once or optional in regex

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

A regex is needed which should have only special character dot which should either be optional or occur only once.

```
pattern = /^([A-Za-z.]+)$/;
```

Comment: @trincot That would validate an empty string because everything is optional. You'd want something like `/^([a-z]+\.?[a-z]*|[a-z]*\.?[a-z]+)$/i`. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it but my coffee only just finished brewing =)

Comment: `/^([a-z]*\.[a-z]*|[a-z]+)$/i` this? Or alternatively with negative lookahead: `/^(?!(.*\.){2})([a-z.]+)$/i`

Comment: 1.) Is `.` valid? (only dot) 2.) Dot anywhere allowed also start/end of string?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information I'd use

```
/^(?!$)[a-z]*\.?[a-z]*$/i
```

The negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) prevents empty matches.

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/J4Z2l4/1)

Comment: With no dot at start/end, another option: [`^\b[a-z]*\.?[a-z]*\b$`](https://regex101.com/r/MNyXEe/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to do it:

1. Deal separately where the input has has *one* dot, with optional letters surrounding it, or *no* dot (but then having at least one letter):

   [`/^([a-z]*\.[a-z]*|[a-z]+)$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/BGHXa0/1)

2. Just capture letters and dots like you did, but don't allow the input to have two dots, using a negative look ahead:

   [`/^(?!(.*\.){2})([a-z.]+)$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/BGHXa0/2)
3. Capture optional letters then an optional point and then optional letters, but forbid an empty input with a negative look-ahead:

   [`/^(?!$)([a-z]*\.?[a-z]*)$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/BGHXa0/3)

Answer (score 1):

If in any case the dot should not be at the start or end and not match an empty string, you can start the match with 1 or more chars a-z and then optionally match a dot and again 1 or more chars a-z:

```
/^[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)?$/i
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAoozO/1)